# SQL - Get records matching with other record in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am using `Amazon RedShift PostgreSQL` database.

There is a table in my database which stores appointment records like this:

```
| id | patientname   | providername | eventid | eventstart          | eventend            | isactive | segmentcode | Description            |
|----|---------------|--------------|---------|---------------------|---------------------|----------|-------------|------------------------|
| 1  | Susie Jones   | John Melton  | 340000  | 2017-08-08 10:00:00 | 2017-08-08 10:00:00 | true     | 845685      | Reminder Call          |
| 2  | Susie Jones   | John Melton  | 340000  | 2017-08-08 10:00:00 | 2017-08-08 10:30:00 | true     | 365478      | Steam Therapy Session  |
| 3  | Roschel Ross  | Kate Winny   | 350000  | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | true     | 845685      | Reminder Call          |
| 4  | Roschel Ross  | Kate Winny   | 350000  | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | 2017-08-09 13:30:00 | true     | 367545      | Physio Therapy Session |
| 5  | Lilly Hodge   | Jessica      | 360000  | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | true     | 754544      | Doctor appointment     |
| 6  | Jack Richards | Mike Chong   | 37000   | 2017-08-10 17:00:00 | 2017-08-10 17:30:00 | true     | 889754      | Sample Appointment     |
| 7  | Sammy Jones   | Winsten      | 38000   | 2017-08-10 17:00:00 | 2017-08-10 18:30:00 | true     | 845685      | Physio Therapy Session |
| 8  | Sammy Jones   | Winsten      | 38000   | 2017-08-10 17:00:00 | 2017-08-10 17:00:00 | true     | 454542      | Reminder Call          |
```

Here, you can see there are some records with **segmentcode 845685**, and all these records are having **a duplicate record with different segment code but the same eventid**.

What I want is, using **SQL query** get the **records with segment code 845685 along with its duplicate record**. So the resultant table will be:

```
| id | patientname   | providername | eventid | eventstart          | eventend            | isactive | segmentcode | Description            |
|----|---------------|--------------|---------|---------------------|---------------------|----------|-------------|------------------------|
| 1  | Susie Jones   | John Melton  | 340000  | 2017-08-08 10:00:00 | 2017-08-08 10:00:00 | true     | 845685      | Reminder Call          |
| 2  | Susie Jones   | John Melton  | 340000  | 2017-08-08 10:00:00 | 2017-08-08 10:30:00 | true     | 365478      | Steam Therapy Session  |
| 3  | Roschel Ross  | Kate Winny   | 350000  | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | true     | 845685      | Reminder Call          |
| 4  | Roschel Ross  | Kate Winny   | 350000  | 2017-08-09 11:00:00 | 2017-08-09 13:30:00 | true     | 367545      | Physio Therapy Session |
| 7  | Sammy Jones   | Winsten      | 38000   | 2017-08-10 17:00:00 | 2017-08-10 18:30:00 | true     | 845685      | Physio Therapy Session |
| 8  | Sammy Jones   | Winsten      | 38000   | 2017-08-10 17:00:00 | 2017-08-10 17:00:00 | true     | 454542      | Reminder Call          |
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simple subquery (as one way), will be sufficient:

```
select * from t 
where eventid in (select eventid from t where segmentcode = 845685)
-- order by eventid, ...
```

another way is using `exists` :

```
select * from t t1
where 
exists (select 1 from t t2 where eventid = t1.eventid and segmentcode = 845685 )
```

thousands of records are not so big amount for modern databases, any way, if performance is not desirable, adding indexes (if not have already) on `eventid` and `segmentcode` should speed up `select` queries.

Comment: Will sub-query with IN perform better? There are thousands of records are there.